# How to parse for specific data from a text file C# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parsing

I am trying to parse through a text file with following data:

[image]

```
A1       COMPANY NAME      COMPANY NAME                                                                    Total Due:     $40,374.56

    Type..Tr Date.Source Doc.Description....Terms..Original Amt......Amount Rem
       1 01/05/21 061775     Invoice          T6      $3,009.71     $3,009.71  
       1 01/08/21 061803     USMMMKTX7F       T6      $2,884.00     $2,884.00  

    Debit Total :         $17,195.04         $17,285.81          $5,893.71               $.00               $.00         $40,374.56
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A1       AAL01           SOMETHING INDUSTRIES INC.                                                          Total Due:     $10,879.70

    Type..Tr Date.Source Doc.Description....Terms..Original Amt......Amount Rem
       1 02/04/21 061957     Invoice          T1      $3,641.90     $3,641.90  
       1 02/11/21 062002     75094100         T1      $4,546.70     $4,546.70  
       1 03/04/21 062128     75094270         T1      $2,691.10     $2,691.10  

    Debit Total :          $7,237.80          $3,641.90               $.00               $.00               $.00         $10,879.70
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A1       ACS01           ALPHA HEALING SYSTEMS                                                          Total Due:      $5,334.20

    Type..Tr Date.Source Doc.Description....Terms..Original Amt......Amount Rem
       1 02/25/21 062076     Invoice          T1      $5,334.20     $5,334.20
```

The data needs to be organized in a way so that the Company Name, Transaction Date, Source ID, and Amount Received are only displayed. Everything else in this text file can be ignored.

Example:

```
[Company Name]    [Transaction Date][SourceID][Amount Received]
COMPANY NAME               01/05/21   061775   $3,009.71   
COMPANY NAME               01/08/21   061803   $2,884.00
SOMETHING INDUSTRIES INC.  02/04/21   061957   $3,641.90
SOMETHING INDUSTRIES INC.  02/11/21   062002   $4,546.70
ALPHA HEALING SYSTEMS      02/25/21   062076   $5,334.20
```

I've tried researching possible solutions all over google and stackoverflow and it seems like using regular expression is general direction to go with this. The problem that needs to be solved is how to skip over all the extra characters and symbols in the text file and only get the required data. What is the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: Wow... uh, where and how are you getting these printouts?

Comment: More than likely that file is generated using fixed-width field rules, you just need to figure that out. Talk to the people who created the file to find out how it's formatted.

Comment: Yeah I would go with fixed width parsing too. It looks like you have half a dozen different record formats to deal with: header/subheader/detail/total, etc. so a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) might be a good approach. It's not difficult, but parsing data in this kind of format is time consuming and extremely fragile. A complete PITA, frankly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Parser using Contain() and Substring() method.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sFileNameOpen);
                
while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    line = line.Trim();
    if (line.ToString() == "" || line.Contains("=======") || line.Contains("A R") || line.Contains("RPC") || line.Contains("--------") || line.Contains("AR Code..") || line.Contains("........") || line.Contains("Last Posting Number:") || line.Contains("Type..") || line.Contains("Grand") || line.Contains("Debit"))
        continue; //skip

    if (line.Contains("Total Due: "))
    {
        customerId = line.Substring(9, 16).Trim();
        custName = line.Substring(25, 41).Trim(); 
        continue;
    }
                    
    if (line.Contains("T0") || line.Contains("T1") || line.Contains("T2") || line.Contains("T3") || line.Contains("T4") || line.Contains("T5") || line.Contains("T6") || line.Contains("T7"))
    {
        txnDate = line.Substring(2, 8).Trim();
        txnNum = line.Substring(11, 6).Trim();
        AmountRemaining = line.Substring(60, 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with a very similar issue about an output via SSH from a server. What I did to overcome such an awful output was not the prettiest work ever but it was functional. First I loaded the file into a string, then read line by line replacing the amount of spaces for a comma, the output was a new CSV string. That way I was able to manipulate the values easier.

Here is part of what I did. Maybe it helps you.

```
                string line = sreader.ReadLine();
                while (line != null) // create a csv file
                {
                    if (line.Contains("CO  --"))
                    {
                        line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s\s\s+", ",");
                        CSV += line + "\r\n";
                        line = sreader.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s\s+", ",");
                        CSV += line + "\r\n";
                        line = sreader.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
```

As you can see above there were lines where I needed to replace 3 spaces and other lines only 2.