# Trying to parse data from text file to single line separated by | symbol

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, desktop-application, text-parsing

I have a text file which has following data:

```
#294448
ORDER_STATUS1098988 VALID
24.09.2021 05:17 AM
Customer_ID: 5524335312265537
MMYY: 08/23
Txn_ID: 74627
Name: Krystal Flowers
E-mail: abc@gmail.com
Phone: 9109153030
Address_original: 1656 W Alvarado dr, Pueblo West, Colorado, 81007, United States
ZIP_City_State_Country: -
Type: -
Subtype: -

#294448
ORDER_STATUS1097728 VALID
24.09.2021 05:17 AM
Customer_ID: 5524331591654699
MMYY: 11/23
Txn_ID: 45617
Name: Allen E Prieto
E-mail: xyz@gmail.com
Phone: 5056994899
Address_original: 655 Ives Dairy Rd, Miami, Florida, 33179, United States
ZIP_City_State_Country: -
Type: -
Subtype: -

#294445
ORDER_STATUS537099 VALID
24.09.2021 05:01 AM
Customer_ID: 4118230087730234
MMYY: 09/25
Txn_ID: 24430
Name: tera casey
Phone: 7405863997
Address_original: 13705 Neptune Lane, New Concord, Ohio State, 43762, PE
ZIP_City_State_Country: 43762, New Concord, Ohio State, UNITED STATES
Subtype: N/A

#294445
ORDER_STATUS489401 VALID
24.09.2021 05:01 AM
Customer_ID: 4118230054806983
MMYY: 07/24
Txn_ID: 13183
Name: Nancy Lambert
Address_original: 2600 loop drive, N, N, 44113, PE
ZIP_City_State_Country: 44113, N, N, UNITED STATES
Subtype: N/A

#294445
ORDER_STATUS437355 VALID
24.09.2021 05:01 AM
Customer_ID: 4118230061412668
MMYY: 05/24
Txn_ID: 55474
Name: Sheets Sherry
E-mail: tyd@gmail.com
Phone: (567) 241-5074
Address_original: 37 Martha Avenue, Mansfield, Ohio, 44905, US
ZIP_City_State_Country: 44905, Mansfield, Ohio, UNITED STATES
Subtype: N/A
```

The data needs to be organized in a way so that the Customer_ID, MMYY and Txn_ID are only displayed in single line separated by | symbol. Everything else in this text file should be ignored.

Example:

```
5524335312265537 | 08/23 | 24430
5524331591654699 | 11/23 | 45617
4118230087730234 | 09/25 | 24430
4118230054806983 | 07/24 | 13183
4118230061412668 | 05/24 | 55474
```

This is what I've tried but I get "Invalid file!" message after the text file is opened.
[Reference taken from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67167242/how-to-parse-for-specific-data-from-a-text-file-c-sharp-visual-studio)

```
private void openFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofdtmp = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofdtmp.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(ofdtmp.FileName))
                    {
                        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                        {
                            string line = sr.ReadLine();
                            line = line.Trim();
                            if (line.ToString() == "" || line.Contains("#") || line.Contains("ORDER_STATUS") || /*Exclude Date & Time*/ line.Contains(".") || line.Contains("Name:") || line.Contains("E-mail:") || line.Contains("Phone:") || line.Contains("Address_original:") || line.Contains("ZIP_City_State_Country:") || line.Contains("Type:") || line.Contains("Subtype:"))
                                continue; //skip

                            if (line.Contains("CustomerID: "))
                            {
                                string customID = line.Substring(12, 29).Trim();
                                continue;
                            }

                            if (line.Contains("MMYY: "))
                            {
                                string mmyy = line.Substring(6, 11).Trim();
                                continue;
                            }

                            if (line.Contains("Txn_ID: "))
                            {
                                string txnID = line.Substring(10, 16).Trim();
                                continue;
                            }   
                        }
                        richTextBox.Text = sr.ToString();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid file!");
                }
            }
        }
```

I've looked up alternative solutions on similar online posts, and it appears that applying regular expression is the right approach to go. The difficulty is to figure out how to skip over all of the unnecessary characters and symbols in the text file and just extract the data that is required. What will be the best solution for this problem?

**Solution update:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RegExTool
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void openFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofdtmp = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofdtmp.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofdtmp.FileName))
                    {
                        string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        richTextBox1.Clear();
                        richTextBox2.Clear();
                        richTextBox1.Text = data;
                        string pattern = @"(?<=CustomerID:).*|(?<=MMYY:).*|(?<=Txn_ID:).*";
                        var en = Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).GetEnumerator();
                        while (en.MoveNext())
                        {
                            var ci = en.Current;
                            if (!en.MoveNext())
                                break;
                            var di = en.Current;
                            if (!en.MoveNext())
                                break;
                            var ti = en.Current;
                            string text = ($"{ci}|{di}|{ti}") + System.Environment.NewLine;
                            richTextBox2.Text += text.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
                        }
                    }
                } 
                catch (Exception ex) 
                { 
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
                }
            }
        }

        private void saveFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tmp = richTextBox2.Text;
            SaveFileDialog svdtmp = new SaveFileDialog();
                if (svdtmp.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.WriteAllText(svdtmp.FileName, (tmp.ToString()));
                        MessageBox.Show("File Saved!");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot save text to file.");
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**Final Solution:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RegExTool
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        static List<string> GetStrings(string input)
        {
            string pattern = @"Customer_ID: (?<CustomerId>\d+)[\r\n]+MMYY\: (?<ExpiryDate>\d{2}\/\d{2})[\r\n]+Txn_ID: (?<TxnId>\d+)";
            List<string> strings = new List<string>();
            foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
            {
                strings.Add($"{match.Groups["CustomerId"]} | {match.Groups["ExpiryDate"]} | {match.Groups["TxnId"]}");
            }
            return strings;
        }

        private void openFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofdtmp = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofdtmp.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofdtmp.FileName))
                    {
                        string input = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        richTextBox1.Clear();
                        richTextBox2.Clear();
                        richTextBox1.Text = input;
                        foreach (var value in GetStrings(input))
                        {
                            string text = value + System.Environment.NewLine;
                            richTextBox2.Text += text;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private void saveFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tmp = richTextBox2.Text;
            SaveFileDialog svdtmp = new SaveFileDialog();
            if (svdtmp.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    File.WriteAllText(svdtmp.FileName, (tmp.ToString()));
                    MessageBox.Show("File Saved!");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot save text to file.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: lets start by actually showing the exception that you get rather than Invalid File message. Add catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) } into your catch clause... Or use Debug.WriteLine()

Comment: @Bola alright got error saying, "Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length".
Update - Edited `line.Substring` in each section to `line.Substring(12, line.Length - 12).Trim();` & `line.Substring(5, line.Length - 5).Trim();`  but this time got result as **text** "System.IO.StreamReader" in _richTextBox_, what went wrong?

Comment: You should trace your code as you should see exactly why it is not working as you expect. To help… inside the… `while (sr.Peek() >= 0)` … loop... the code reads several lines from the file, the problem for you is how are you going to know “when” the last line read from the file is the “END” of one of the lines you want to add to the text box? The code sets three variables after x number of lines have been read… `string customID = line.Substring(12, 29).Trim();` … however, the code does nothing with those values.

Comment: I would assume that you may want something like…  `richTextBox1.Text += customID + " | " + mmyy + " | " + txnID + Environment.NewLine;`. As I mentioned previously… you will need to figure out how you are going to tell “when” to add the line to the text box. Possibly set each variable null, and then when all three variables are NOT null then you would know to add the line to the text box, and then reset all the variables back to null. Crude, but it should work.

Comment: @JohnG I've replaced the line where `richTextBox.Text = sr.ToString();` to `richTextBox.Text += customID + " | " + mmyy + " | " + txnID + Environment.NewLine;` but error says, "The name customID/mmyy/txnID does not exist in the current context."

Comment: That is because you have “defined” those variables “inside” the `if` statements. They go out of scope as soon as the `if` statement exits. This is what I mean by they are never used. You need to “define” the variables outside the `if` statements. In addition I would suggest you define the variables “outside” the `while` loop as it is unnecessary to “redefine" the variables in each loop iteration.

Comment: @JohnG added `string customID = null; string mmyy = null; string txnID = null;` before while loop and then where while loop close before that line added `richTextBox.Text += customID + " | " + mmyy + " | " + txnID + Environment.NewLine;` still nothing happened in the output. I got the idea of resetting the existing values of variables.

Comment: Well… you want the line… `richTextBox.Text += customID + …` to be “inside” the `while` loop, however you do not want it to be called with every iteration of the loop. In my crude example… you could wrap the line of code in an `if` statement that checks to see if all three variables are NOT `null`. If all three variables are NOT `null` then that would be the trigger to let you know that you want to add the line to the text box. Add the line to the text box then reset all three variables back to `null`. Please note this is a crude example and I am confident there are better ways to do this.

Comment: Lastly, you should note that when you move the line `richTextBox.Text += customID + …` into the `while` loop… you will want to remove the `continue` lines. I would dump the first `if` statement all together, but more important is that any code you put “after” the last `if` statement (like the one we need above) will never get executed because all the `if`s branch back up to the begging of the loop. Granted if the line did not match any of the strings we were looking for… then the code would execute… but that is not what you want. You may want to [edit] your question and add the updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution using regex. Taking care of linebreaks on
• Windows **\r\n**
• Linux **\n**
• MacOS **\r**

You can test/run this code on https://replit.com/@JomaCorpFX/SO70374465

You can check the the regex on https://regex101.com/r/R7Q5bq/4

**Code**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    static List<string> GetStrings(string input)
    {
        string pattern = @"Customer_ID: (?<CustomerId>\d+)[\r\n]+MMYY\: (?<ExpiryDate>\d{2}\/\d{2})[\r\n]+Txn_ID: (?<TxnId>\d+)";
        List<string> strings = new List<string>();
        foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
        {
            strings.Add($"{match.Groups["CustomerId"]} | {match.Groups["ExpiryDate"]} | {match.Groups["TxnId"]}");
        }
        return strings;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = @"#294448
ORDER_STATUS1098988 VALID
24.09.2021 05:17 AM
Customer_ID: 5524335312265537
MMYY: 08/23
Txn_ID: 74627
Name: Krystal Flowers
E-mail: abc@gmail.com
Phone: 9109153030
Address_original: 1656 W Alvarado dr, Pueblo West, Colorado, 81007, United States
ZIP_City_State_Country: -
Type: -
Subtype: -

#294448
ORDER_STATUS1097728 VALID
24.09.2021 05:17 PM
Customer_ID: 5524331591654699
MMYY: 11/23
Txn_ID: 45617
Name: Allen E Prieto
E-mail: xyz@gmail.com
Phone: 5056994899
Address_original: 655 Ives Dairy Rd, Miami, Florida, 33179, United States
ZIP_City_State_Country: -
Type: -
Subtype: -

#294445
ORDER_STATUS537099 VALID
24.09.2021 05:01 AM
Customer_ID: 4118230087730234
MMYY: 09/25
Txn_ID: 24430
Name: tera casey
Phone: 7405863997
Address_original: 13705 Neptune Lane, New Concord, Ohio State, 43762, PE
ZIP_City_State_Country: 43762, New Concord, Ohio State, UNITED STATES
Subtype: N/A

#294445
ORDER_STATUS489401 VALID
24.09.2021 05:01 AM
Customer_ID: 4118230054806983
MMYY: 07/24
Txn_ID: 13183
Name: Nancy Lambert
Address_original: 2600 loop drive, N, N, 44113, PE
ZIP_City_State_Country: 44113, N, N, UNITED STATES
Subtype: N/A

#294445
ORDER_STATUS437355 VALID
24.09.2021 05:01 AM
Customer_ID: 4118230061412668
MMYY: 05/24
Txn_ID: 55474
Name: Sheets Sherry
E-mail: tyd@gmail.com
Phone: (567) 241-5074
Address_original: 37 Martha Avenue, Mansfield, Ohio, 44905, US
ZIP_City_State_Country: 44905, Mansfield, Ohio, UNITED STATES
Subtype: N/A";
        foreach (var value in GetStrings(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
5524335312265537 | 08/23 | 74627
5524331591654699 | 11/23 | 45617
4118230087730234 | 09/25 | 24430
4118230054806983 | 07/24 | 13183
4118230061412668 | 05/24 | 55474
```

**References**

[Regex Match Method - Match(String, String, RegexOptions, TimeSpan)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=net-6.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Match_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_System_TimeSpan_)

Comment: [Joma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3158594/joma) After just pasting the code in VS got Error: No overload for method 'Matches' takes 4 arguments.

Comment: What versión of framework you use? Maybe your target framework is 4.0. To avoid this issue remove the last parameter ```TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)```

Comment: [Joma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3158594/joma) Yes, now set to target framework 4.5. Your solution worked in the worst case scenario. Got results with new line text in previous solution. Updated code in the post!

Comment: The matchTimeout parameter specifies how long a pattern matching method should try to find a match before it times out. Setting a time-out interval prevents regular expressions that rely on excessive backtracking from appearing to stop responding when they process input that contains near matches. For more information, see Best Practices for Regular Expressions and Backtracking. If no match is found in that time interval, the method throws a RegexMatchTimeoutException exception. matchTimeout overrides any default time-out value defined for the application domain in which the method executes.